# Парсинг музыки ВК

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[image: APIVK]

Решил сохранить названия своих треков.Узнал о парсинге, поизучал.Смог запарсить обычные сайты с помощью Python.
С ВК проблема - Api недоступно(Прикреплена фотография) - https://vk.com/dev/audio_api
Инспектор кода не показывает ничего путного, что можно было бы использовать для авторизации
Подскажите.

Вот всё , что есть, без авторизации

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



r = requests.get('https://vk.com/audios181859003')
html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select('.audio_row__title_inner'):

    print(el.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api)

Пример кода для загрузки музыки:

```
 import vk_api
 from vk_api import audio

 vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=vk_login, password=vk_password, auth_handler=two_step_auth)
 vk_session.auth()
 vk = vk_session.get_api()
 vk_audio = audio.VkAudio(vk_session)

for i in vk_audio.get(owner_id=v_id):
                try:
                    song += 1
                    r = requests.get(i['url'], stream=True)
                    size = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])
                    if r.status_code == 200:
                        with open(str(song) + '_' + i['artist'] + ' - ' + i['title'] + '.mp3', 'wb') as file:
                            print('Загрузка:', i['artist'] + ' - ' + i['title'])
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            for data in tqdm(iterable=r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), total=size / 1024, unit='KB',
                                             leave=True):
                                file.write(data)
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/spajf4 
line 22

                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: перед for добавьте song = 0. https://github.com/violet1one/vk_music

Comment: https://prnt.sc/spazrx проблема всё та же

Comment: посмотрите код с github. я проверил его - работоспособен

Comment: Неожиданный конец файла во время анализа — EOF значит «End of File» (конец файла).

Это значит, что текст вашего кода окончился преждевременно — компилятор еще что-то ожидал, но ваш код окончился перед тем, как это настало.

Обычной причиной бывает, что вы что-то начали а не закончили — кавычку, апостроф, скобку (круглую, квадратную, фигурную): " ' ( [ {.

Comment: Попробовал.Спасибо, но ошибка загрузки.И мне не нужно её скачивать.Я хочу запарсить только названия

Comment: за загрузку отвечает строка for data in tqdm. а до нее print('Загрузка:', i['artist'] + ' - ' + i['title']) видимо то, что вам и требуется

Comment: Убрал её.Всёравно всё работает.Попробовал убрать "Ошибка загрузки " , что бы просто получить названия песен - получил, но только началось всё с 244 песни.Мб проблема терминала VS Code

Comment: Кстати, а есть способ получения конкретной песни по прямой вк-ссылке без авторизации на самом сайте?